# Mahout servlets per data model

Tags: tomcat, servlets, mahout, collaborative-filtering

I am implementing the Mahout user-based recommendation engine where the recommendations will be served via `RecommenderServlet` running in Tomcat.

So far looks like a basic setup, but it has some extra properties:

1. Recommendations will be served from 100 different data models, depending on user's context. Each data model is ~2 Mb.
2. There could be 1000s of concurrent users querying recommendations at a given time.

One option I considered is setting up one `RecommenderServlet` per data model. So there will be 100 of them distributed between multiple Tomcat instances.

**The main question for Mahout experts:**

Would you recommend to set up one `RecommenderServlet` per data model, or there are better alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that choice really makes a difference to the issues of performance you mention.

It's more about what makes more logical sense to you. A servlet typically provides one logical service and answers one "type" of request -- for a page, or method. In theory you could have one servlet serve everything on your site but it would be ugly, design-wise.

My rule of thumb would be to use different servlets for different URL paths.

It's not going to change the memory requirements or performance though. Either way you're serving those requests, from that data in memory.

Now, you could in fact dedicate whole instances of Tomcat to serving only a subset of those 100 models. But then you're really running different web apps, on different servers. It's no longer a question of 1 or 100 servlets, but a bigger choice of splitting up your architecture.

Comment: Thanks. You are right, this is an architectural question. However there is one Mahout specific aspect I would like to clarify. Each RecommenderServlet uses one Recommender object. Each Recommender uses a data model and loads it in the servlet's init(). That led me to conclusion that having different data models requires separate servlets. Isn't it true?

Comment: Oh I see. If you're using `RecommenderServlet` as-is then yes it's built to handle one `Recommender`. But that's more of a convenience, and an example, for quick demos or prototypes. For your use case, I'd be writing your own custom servlets. And those can do whatever you want. Though I'd still probably end up using one servlet per logical service, and I imagine you have one model/recommender per logical service.